# I can't figure out why the onclick action doesn't work in electron

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

[electron, typescript, react]

Currently, I am working on an application in electron and react typescript.
I can use onClick in normal react, but when I create it in electron, it doesn't work.
do I need to write something special in electron?

`render.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {HashRouter,Link,Route,Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Home';

const App: React.VFC = () => {

    return (
      <HashRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="menu">
          <Link to="/"><button className="btn btn-primary">Home</button></Link>
          <Link to="/folder"><button className="btn btn-primary">Folders</button></Link>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/folder" component={Folders}/>
        </Switch>     
      </div>
      </HashRouter>    
    );
  }


  const Folders = () => {

    const clickHandler = () => {
        console.log('foo')
    }  
    return (  
      
      <div className="d-flex flex-column w-25">
          <button className="button" onClick={()=>clickHandler()}>hoge</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: try onClickCapture too if that works.

Answer (score 0):

huum.

I wrote  `<!-- <script src="renderer.js"></script> -->` in html file.
I don't know what caused it, but this seemed to interfere with it.